# Python read/write pickled file

Tags: python, performance, file, serialization, compression

Is there a way in Python 2.7 to improve reading/writing speed (or memory consumption of the file) compared to this version?

```
import gzip
import cPickle
import io

# save zipped and pickled file
def save_zipped_pickle(obj, filename):
    # disable garbage collector (hack for faster reading/writing)
    gc.disable()
    with gzip.open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        cPickle.dump(obj, io.BufferedWriter(f), -1)
        # enable garbage collector again
        gc.enable()

# load zipped and pickled file
def load_zipped_pickle(filename):
    # disable garbage collector (hack for faster reading/writing)
    gc.disable()
    with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        loaded_object = cPickle.load(io.BufferedReader(f))
        # enable garbage collector again
        gc.enable()
        return loaded_object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks really efficient and potentially the best you can do, but here are some thoughts:

- try specifying the [highest protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) (for Python 2.7 that would be protocol 2):

  ```
  with gzip.open(filename, 'wb') as f:
      cPickle.dump(obj, io.BufferedWriter(f), protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  ```
- re-iterate over the serialization format itself - if JSON is an option, [`ujson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson) might win the performance battle against `cPickle`
- see if [`PyPy`](https://pypy.org/) is an option
- you can also get [`Cython`](http://cython.org/) into play here - there are [famous stories how just specifying types with Cython leads to serious performance gains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1MSX7V28Po&t=9s)
- there is also this undocumented [`.fast` option/flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15108940/771848), but I am not at all sure it would actually help to speed things up - too good to be true :)
- as far as improving on memory, you can try [chunking with `shutil`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22791403/771848)

FYI, the `gc.disable`/`gc.enable()` pair is [planned to be implemented as a context manager in Python 3.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue31356). You can borrow a Python sample from the issue tracker:

```
@contextmanager
def gc_disabled():
    if gc.isenabled():
        gc.disable()
        yield
        gc.enable()
    else:
        yield
```